# Countably compact $E_{1}$ spaces is maximal countably compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

***A topological space is an $ E_{1}$ space if every point is the intersection of a countable number of closed neighborhoods.***

(1) why is it right that **$ E_{1}$ spaces are Hausdorff** and that **first countable Hausdorff spacess are** $E_{1}$?

(2) why is it right that every **countably compact $E_{1}$ spacesis maximal countably compact ?**

Comment: Are these homework or you are self-studying?

Comment: Does it make sense to answer you? Since you have never reacted to any answer (with none of your profiles).

Comment: I think personally he/she is preparing some kind of thesis on KC spaces and related subjects and is struggling with the literature.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: That could be reason for having multiple profiles but not to not react at all. Also, there are consultations.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$HINTS:

Let $X$ be $E_1$, and let $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y$. There are open nbhds $U_n$ of $x$ for $n\in\omega$ such that $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}\cl U_n=\{x\}$. Clearly, then there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $y\notin\cl U_n$. From here you should be able to conclude easily that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Now suppose that $X$ is first countable and Hausdorff, let $x\in X$, and let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a countable base of open sets at $x$. Using the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff, what can you say about $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}\cl B_n$?

Suppose that $X$ is $E_1$ and countably compact. To show that $X$ is maximal countably compact, it suffices to show that every countably compact subset of $X$ is closed. Suppose that $K\subseteq X$ is countably compact, and let $x\in X\setminus K$; we want to show that $x$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that $U\cap K=\varnothing$. Let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a family of open nbhds of $x$ such that $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}\cl U_n=\{x\}$, and consider the open cover $\mathscr{V}=\{X\setminus\cl U_n:n\in\omega\}$ of $K$.